# How to connect php and hana?

Tags: php, database-connection, hana

```
$driver         = "HANADB"; 
$servername  = "sercername";
$schema       = "schemaname"; 
$username       = "user"; 
$password       = "XXXX";

$conn=odbc_connect("Driver={HANADB};Server=$servername;Schema=$db_name;",
 $username, $password);}
```

I am using an odbc connection to try and connect to my hana schema. However, when i connect I get the following message

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source 
name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in
```

I am not really sure as to where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If the HANA client is installed, the ODBC drivers are automatically added to your host.

May be you want to use the optional parameter *cursor_type* = SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC ??
Check: http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php

$conn = odbc_connect("", "", "", SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the 32bit ODBC Administrator to create your connection.

The 32bit ODBC admin is run from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe 
The 64bit ODBC admin is run from C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe

The 32 bit driver will show up in the list of available drivers as HDBODBC32.

Follow [HANA Academy - Installing the 32bit HANA Client](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=au7eziBLAtU) for more detailed explanation

Answer (score -2):

Why not using Server Side JavaScript provided by SAP?

I recommend reading chapter 8 "Writing Server-Side JavaScript Code" of the [SAP HANA Developer Guide](http://scn.sap.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/60319-102-1-222335/SAP_HANA_Developer_Guide_en.pdf)